# Limiting chosen variables solved for in opensolver

Tags: vba, limit, linear-programming, solver

I've got a linear system of 17 equations, 506 variables that solve for a minimum summation of the total variables. This works fine, so far, but the solution is a result of a combination of 19 variables.

But in the end I want to limit the amount of chosen variables to 10, without knowing in advance which ones are the optimal ones (The solver figures that out for me, as well as their ratio).

I figured I can set a boolean = 1 if the value becomes larger than 0: (meaning the variable is picked), and 0 if the variable is not picked for an optimal solution.

And then have the sum of the booleans be 10 at most.

However this seems a bit elaborate, and I was wondering whether there was a built in option in the opensolver, for I think it is quite a common problem to solve a large set with a subset.

So does anyone have a suggestion on:

1. How my elaborate way drastically decreases performance? (*I have no intrinsic comprehension of the opensolver algorithms, yet.)
2. A suggestion to more easily/within the opensolver options account for my desire of max. 10 solution variables?

Based on the information provided below, I first scaled down the size of the problem:

I have three lists of data with 18 entries in columns:

`W7:W23,AC7:AD23`

which manually (with: `W28 = 6000, AC28=600,W29 = 1,AC29 =1`), in a linear combination,equal/exceed the target list:
`EGM34:EG50`

So what I did was put the descion variables in `W28:W29, AC28:AD29`
Where I added the constraint `W28,AC28:AD28 = integer` in the solver (both the original excel solver as in opensolver)

And I added the constraint `W29,AC29:AD29 = Boolean` in the solver (both the original excel solver as in opensolver)

Then I have a multiplication of the integer*boolean = the actual multiplication factor for the above lists in `(W7:W23 etc)`

In order to limit the nr of chosen variables I have also tried, in addition to the described constraints, to limit the cell with `=sum(W29,AC29:AD29) to <= 10` (effectively reducing the amount of booleans set to true below 11, or so I thought, but the booleans aren't evaluated as booleans by the solver).

These new multiplied lists are placed in `W34:W50,AC34:AD50`, and the summation is situated in: `EGY34:EGY50` Hence the final check is added as a constraint as:

`EGY34:EGY50 =>EGM34:EGM50`

And I had a question about how the linear solver evaluates these constraints, does it:

a. Think the sum of `EGY34:EGY50 must be larger or equal than/to EGM34:EGM50`

or

b. Does it think: "for every row x `EGYx must be larger or equal than/to EGMx`

So far I've noted b. but I would like to make sure.

**But my main question concerns:**

After using the Evolutionary algorithm as was kindly suggested in the comments below, how/why does it try values as 0.99994 for the desicion variables designated as booleans?

Comment: Sorry. This is often called a "cardinality constraint". No way around extra binary variables to count nonzero solution values.

Comment: And yes, it *is* expected to slow down the solving time - very probably a lot :(

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you! I think it is marvellous that whenever I seem to stumble upon a problem, it turns out there is actually a name for it, as well as a way to deal with it in practice. I will look up cardinality constraints and try to understand how it relates to my problem.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are doing but when we want at most `N` of the `x(i)>=0` to be nonzero, we can introduce a binary variable `b(i)` and add the constraints `x(i)<=b(i)*xup(i)` -- here `xup(i)` is an upper bound on `x(i)` --, and `sum(i,b(i))<=N`. No need for integer restrictions on `x`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen that is indeed what I am trying to do, but I did not one could add a multiplication in the righthand side of the constraint equation. I just tried it out! Thank you! I am going to rewrite my model with the binary and upperbound multiplication on the righthandside of the equations :)
 Though the integer variables at the first instance were for 2 reasons, to ensure my computation goes in steps of 10, because the summation a multiplication of desicion variable with list*10, and to speed up computation if it only has to compute whole integers instead of fractions as well.

Comment: This does not make sense at all. The right-hand side can be moved to the left, and also your statement about integers is simply wrong. I suggest to sit down with your professor and have him/her explain things in more detail.

Comment: I would agree with you about the equality but I got the error message "left hand side must be a range" when I tried to add a constraint with `=$W$28*$W$29` so I thought a multiplication without the `=` so `$W$28*$W$29`  was not a range, hence I thought the left hand side could not contain multiplications, not knowing it was the notation rather than the multiplication that proved erroneous. As for the integers, I had imagined it would reduce the options available hence reduce the computation but I apparently am wrong, thank you for the direct feedback!

Comment: And I do not have any professor guiding me and had to learn this just by searching, trial and error, so I am grateful for your suggestions! But that is an excellent idea and I will contact one to see if I can get a better understanding of the matter. For there often is a large gap between the level of my understanding and the level of required understanding to comprehend the information in the suggestions I receive on where I can find information on the problem I'm facing, human interaction removes that gap.

Comment: `x(i)<=b(i)*xup(i)` can be written as `x(i)-b(i)*xup(i)<=0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The introduction of binary variables is indeed the standard way to implement such constraints. Unfortunately, it transforms the problem from being a linear programming problem to being an [integer programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (specifically a mixed integer linear programming problem). A standard approach to such problems is the [branch and bound algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound). This is what Excel's built-in solver seems to use, I'm not sure about the open solver that you are using. In the best case (where there is a lot of bounding) it will run fairly rapidly, even with problems of your size. In the worst case, for your problem it could be little better than what you would get by running the simplex algorithm `C(506,10) = 2.8 x 10^20` times (once for each possible set of 10 decision variables). In other words, it might be infeasible. Integer programming is known to be NP-hard.

If an exact solution is infeasible, you could always use a heuristic algorithm such as an evolutionary approach.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried solving it through the evolutionary algorithm of the conventional excel solver with a drastically reduced problem size, to ensure I comprehend what's going on and ensure the problem is set up correct. But I've noticed that the booleans are not evaluated as booleans. I expect it is because I think the solver functions different than how I imagine it does, which leads me to set boundary conditions/constraints that are unworkable for the solver. I am reading up on the problem types and try to apply that back into the problem-solver relationships.